# Docker Swarm - “Error getting node <id>: node <id> not found” repeated. Manger node continues looking for removed node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

- OS : CentOS 7, Kernel 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
- Docker version : 19.03.12 Community, API 1.40

Hello,

I was running a Docker Swarm cluster, with 3 manager and 9 workers.

Yesterday, for unknown reason, the cluster was broken and I reinitialized (`docker swarm init --force-new-cluster`) on one manager and make other nodes join the cluster again.

Now there is only one manager(let's call it m1), and the m1 node is printing out such log every seconds (/var/log/messages):

```
Nov 27 14:37:47 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:47.972559924+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut: node 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut not found"
Nov 27 14:37:47 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:47.973323970+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node i4i2f2pxh3896nnfnpbv5h143: node i4i2f2pxh3896nnfnpbv5h143 not found"
Nov 27 14:37:47 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:47.973882459+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node xkig9cw27h9x64lqnv743s5g4: node xkig9cw27h9x64lqnv743s5g4 not found"
Nov 27 14:37:49 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:49.090099529+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut: node 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut not found"
Nov 27 14:37:49 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:49.090776238+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node i4i2f2pxh3896nnfnpbv5h143: node i4i2f2pxh3896nnfnpbv5h143 not found"
Nov 27 14:37:49 PYSTOMGT dockerd: time="2020-11-27T14:37:49.091393776+09:00" level=error msg="Error getting node xkig9cw27h9x64lqnv743s5g4: node xkig9cw27h9x64lqnv743s5g4 not found"
...
```

Those three IDs (`2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut`, `i4i2....`, `xkig...`) were the IDs that had been assigned to three worker nodes (say, w1, w2, w3).

When I was trying to recover the cluster yesterday, I did

```
# on m1
docker swarm init --force-new-cluster

# then, on w1
docker swarm leave --force
docker swarm join --token .... m1:2377
(I guess the ID of w1 was changed from 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut to new one at this point)

# same on w2 and w3
```

For now, there is no node with ID `2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut` but the manager node is still looking for it.

I can not even remove the node by ID:

```
# on m1
# docker node rm 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut
Error: No such node: 2rcgf7rzqvojr4yzyx3ko13ut
```

What can I do now? I hope restarting docker daemon on m1 might help, but I'm afraid that the cluster would be broken again. This is a live service environment so I want to be very careful.

You might say, "Firstly, promote more nodes as managers. Then try to restart dockerd on the manager".
I tried it yesterday. But `docker node promote m2 m3` command hung, suddenly I lost quorum on m1, I could not do any Swarm operation, and finally I had to reinitialize cluster again... So I'm planning to reboot every nodes and initialize the whole cluster from scratch on next maintenance day, months later. I think this is another topic. For now, I just want to make the m1 manager STOP looking for those 3 nodes.

Thanks.

EDIT:

After two weeks, on our regular maintenance day, I planned to `docker stack rm` all the Docker stacks, restart Docker daemon on m1 and (if needed) other nodes, and (if the problem still remained) reinitialize whole the Swarm cluster.

But as soon as I removed one of the Docker stack, suddenly Docker daemon on m1 stopped outputting the "node not found" messages. Then I could promote other nodes as managers. It seemed everything began to work fine.

So... I could not find the exact cause of this problem. I just guess that the stack information was not updated properly when I reinitialized the swarm cluster, therefore the manager kept trying to find non-existing nodes to distribute containers on.